# Google Apps Script - Getting the value from the cell where I call the function

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to make a simple script to set the last modified time when a checkbox turns on. At this point it's ok.

Another script cleans all the checkboxes once a week, so I lost all the times registered.

I think I just need to get the value from the cell which is, at the same time, the caller.

I tried classic functions from SpreedsheetApp, but can't get this value.

```
function lastUpdate(x) {
  if(x == true){
    return new Date();
  } else if (x == false) {
    //Get previous registered value to return.
  }
}
```

[Sample sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tKISFYvnhDjWACljrxfH1OaSle1gLDb01ZzOgD9uhYU/edit?pli=1#gid=0)

Comment: Have you consider using an onEdit

Comment: I tried but I only can apply the changes in the edited cell. I just add a link in the main post with a sample sheet.

Comment: an onEdit() triggered function can make changes to the entire sheet.  If you are having difficulties with permissions then try using an installable trigger

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand the situation, you want to log the date/time when a checkbox is first turned on and ignore it if the checkbox is turned off (or if it was turned on after having previously been on already), is that right?

Looking at the sheet/code you provided, it looks like you are correctly leveraging the `onEdit` function as was mentioned in the comments, but you are using `getActiveCell` as opposed to the [onEdit Event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit) to make the changes. If you use the Event object, you will have access to the `oldValue`, the new value (`value`), and the rest of the spreadsheet, which you can use to perform some conditional code (ie run only if a checkbox in a specific range has been edited and update the date only if the checkbox has been turned on for the first time). To use the event object, you only need to pass it in as an argument like so:

```
function onEdit(e) {
   ...
   if (e.oldValue !== true) {
   //some code
   }
   ...
}
```